# Quicksight - Ifelse Expression giving wrong values

Tags: if-statement, expression, amazon-quicksight, calculated-field

I am trying to use ifelse expression to show custom percentages.

The issue is for Others group, value is being shown as wrong.

Below is my ifelse expression.

ifelse(Group = 'a', 0.28, Group = 'b', 0.057, Group = 'c', 0.1290, Group = 'd', 0.032, Group = 'e', 0.032, Group = 'f', 0.043, Group = 'g', 0.075, Group = 'h', 0.048, Group = 'i', 0.022, Group = 'j', 0.1, 0.182)

Below is the screenshot of percentages in the same order and last is the value for "Others" group which was actually supposed to be 0.18 but showing as 39.31. Due to this total is also showing wrong

[image]

I am unable to find any issue with my expression.

Please help.